# quip invalid access token

Tags: access, quip

I'm trying to test the quip API in Python to autogenerate documents.
I'm not an admin at my org and I've generated a personal token using
quip.com/dev/token in my organization website.

The code at the end always returns: 401, invalid access_token.
The same happens if I try other endpoints for example to create a new doc.

Any suggestion on how to make it work?
Not being an admin, can I generate the token in other ways?
Thank you,
Marti

---

```
def get_root_folder_id(access_token):
    base_url = 'https://platform.quip.com/1/'
    endpoint = 'users/current'

    # Headers for the request
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    # Send GET request to get current user
    response = requests.get(base_url + endpoint, headers=headers)
    print("HTTP status code:", response.status_code)
    print("HTTP response body:", response.text)
```